# How to calculate $(3+4i)\cdot(1+i)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have recently read an article on imaginary numbers. It was very interesting, but left me with the above question. It had the answer in the question, it was $-1+7i$. But how do I calculate this?

Comment: Try using ordinary multiplication, replacing $i^2$ with $-1$ when needed.

Comment: Think of $3+4i$ as a pair of numbers $(3,4)$ with the multiplication rule $(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (ac-bd, ad+bc)$. Then $(3+4i)\cdot (1+i) = (3,4) \cdot (1,1) = (-1,7) = -1+7i$. In particular, $i = (0,1)$ which gives $i^2 = (0,1)^2 = (-1,0) = -1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(3+4i)\cdot(1+i)$

$= 3+4i+3i+4\cdot i^{2}$

$= 3+7i + 4\cdot i^{2}$

$i$ can be represented as  ${\sqrt{-1}}$

So, ${i^{2} = -1}$

So, the above can be writen as :

$3+7i-4 = -1+7i$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just didn't understand how `i` could be used in maths until today.

Comment: @enzotib: Thanks

Comment: Argh! That is a horribly non-standard use of $\Longrightarrow$. Please don't do that when you just mean $=$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I have edited

Answer (score 3):

For complex numbers many of the rules for real numbers also hold. In particular the distributive law, so you can multiply out:
\begin{align*}
(3+4i)\cdot (1+i)&= 3\cdot (1+i) + 4i\cdot (1+i)\\
&= 3\cdot 1 + 3\cdot i + 4i\cdot 1+ 4i\cdot i\\
&= 3 + 3i + 4i + 4\cdot (-1)\\
&= -1 + 7i
\end{align*}

Comment: I presume you meant 'rules for real numbers also hold'?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic binomial multiplication. Using the fact that $(a + b)\cdot(c + d) = ac + ad + bc + bd $, we have,$$\begin{align}(3 + 4i)\cdot (1 + i) & = &3 + 3i + 4i + 4i^2 \\ & = & 4i^2 + 7i + 3\\ & = & 4(-1) + 7i + 3\\ & = & -4 + 7i + 3\\&=&7i - 1 \text{ which could be written as}-1+7i  \end{align}$$**Important Note: In step 3,  the fact that $i^2 = -1$ is used.**